# What do the Stone-Cech compactification's youger brothers look like?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, ring-theory

$X$ is a non-compact completely-regular space. $C(X)$ is the ring of continuous functions $X \to \mathbb R$. The Stone-Cech compactification $\beta(X)$ is the space of all multiplicative linear functionals $C(X) \to \mathbb R$, under the pointwise topology.

$\beta(X) \  -$ in particular $\beta(\mathbb R) \ -$ is a well-studied space. It is compact and satisfies a universal property about extending continuous functions on $X$. Many of its topological properties are known to be independent of ZFC.

But what if we only consider a subring $A \subset C(X)$ and the space of all multiplicative linear functionals $A \to \mathbb R$? Call the associated compactification $Y$. Then by Gelfand duality there is a continuous surjection $\beta(X) \to Y$ and so $Y$ is compact, and connected if $X$ is connected.

But what else is known about $Y$? What properties does it share with $\beta(X)$ and what properties can we change by choosing $A$ differently? For example what is known when $X = \mathbb R$ and $A$ is any of the following subrings:

$A = C^1(X)$ the ring of once-differentiable functions

$A = C^\infty(X)$ the ring  of smooth functions

$A = P(X)$ the ring of polynomials

$A = L(X)$ the ring of Lipschitz functions

I can easily believe all the $Y$'s satisfy a corresponding property about lifting the elements of $A$ to $Y$. But what else?

Or does all of these $A$'s being dense in $C(X)$ just turn out that $Y = \beta(X)$?